# Решает ли данный код поставленную задачу? Если нет, что нужно добавить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача следующая:
Дана строка из символов латинского алфавита.
Вставьте пробел перед каждой заглавной буквой.
Перед первой буквой пробел добавлять не надо. Пример.

Исходная строка:

```
AtTimesYouMayWantToReadDataFromTheKeyBoard
```

Полученная строка:

```
At Times You May Want To Read Data From The Key Board
```

Код:

```
s = input('Введите строку: ')
to = 0

if s:
    to = s[0]
    for i in s[1:]:
        if i.isupper():
            to += f' {i}'
    print(to)
        else:
            to += i
else:
    print('Try again')
```

Comment: Вы что, где-то добыли код, и теперь сомневаетесь - для этой ли он задачи?

Comment: Пожалуй, что мой вопрос поставлен не так. Правильно ли выполнено задание? И в полной ли мере подходит данный код или нет

Comment: Сделайте несколько тестов. f-форматирование здесь не нужно

Comment: а самостоятельно выяснить, правильно ли код выполняет указанную задачу, почему не получается?

Comment: Пожалуй, что я исчерпал свои силы. Я решил обратиться за помощью, ведь я только новичок в данной области.

Comment: Какие силы? Вы даже не можете  просто глазами посмотреть добавляются ли пробелы перед заглавными буквами?

Comment: Строку `to += f' {i}'` замените на `to += f'{i}'` или `to += ' ' + i` и все заработает как надо. + `print(to)` перенесите из цикла в конец программы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520560/swad, спасибо, что не остались равнодушными. Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @Crimson Для обращения к кому либо, можно использовать символ @ ) Тогда и уведомление приходит

Comment: @SwaD Ещё раз спасибо ^_^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pip install inflection`

```py
import inflection as inf
print(inf.titleize('AtTimesYouMayWantToReadDataFromTheKeyBoard'))
# At Times You May Want To Read Data From The Key Board
```

UPD

```py
text = 'AtTimesYouMayWantToReadDataFromTheKeyBoard'

def append_space(s: str):
    return ''.join((' ' if x.isupper() else '') + x for x in s ).strip()

print(append_space(text))
# At Times You May Want To Read Data From The Key Board
```